# option element onclick event fix for chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, event-handling

I am probably wasting my time with this question but here goes.
Chrome and Opera do not handle events in option elements IE and Firefox do.

So I am wondering I some knows a workaround other than using onchange in the select element, as I have tried to work with that event and pull errors of null value.

```
onchange="side_nav(this.getAttibute('id'))"
```

The code I am using is simple id change that works sweet in anything but option elements in chrome and opera, This is the function.

```
 function side_nav(id)
 {
document.getElementById("selectedS").setAttribute("id","");
 id.setAttribute("id","selectedS");
 }
```

Like I said it works with this in the option element but only in IE and FireFox

```
onclick="side_nav(this)"
```

The function works sweet in buttons and I suspect every other element also, just not the one I am set up to use.

I suspect I will have rewrite the nav panel to fix the problem, but thought I would ask someone else there thoughts.

Comment: "side_nav(this.getAttibute('id')" missing parenthesese?

Comment: To what are you attaching the 'onchange' event? To `option` or `select`? I'd say it'd need to be the latter. Using jQuery this definitely works: `$('select').on('change', function(){});`.

Comment: The select is the all that will fire in GC and FF and the event fires with onchange but the null value screws up the getAttribute method and returns an error.

Comment: Yes I forgot the parentheses at the end here as I hand wrote it quickly. I have edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

This is What I believe is the answer. not well written but addresses the issue with an answer.

This is a response to Chrome bug reporting. [The actual post](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370743)

Fist I must say after further evaluation I believe that this is not as much a bug or defect but is in how the browser handles the select and option elements. As I see this the browser sees the option element/tag more as an attribute of the select element rather than than an individual element. The select element/tag is just a multidimensional array in HTML and the option tags become attributes of the select element which is why events do not fire and is also why it is impossible to style the option element/tag. I see now that this is deep in source code and seems to be split up equally between the top four browsers. I'll put the basic select code that I have been working with but it will be of no help as it is just the norm, and as I said, it's not a bug but program design.
Thanks for the response.